# CDI Entity Listeners - EclipseLink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, cdi

I am trying to do something like

https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Release/2.5/JPA21#CDI_Entity_Listeners

but non of my injections are working.

Does Entity Listener doesn't inject CDI dependencies ?

Do we have to do something different.

```
public class EntityListener {

    @Inject
  private UserUtility userUtility;

   @PrePersist
   public void prePersist(Object object) {
       logger.log("prepersist", object);
   }

   @PostPersist
   public void postPersist(Object object){
      object.createUser(userUtility.getLoggedInUser())
   }


 }
```

But my userUtility is always null, I am using userUtility in different places in my project and It is properly injected.
Just not in here.

Any clues, Please help me.

Comment: Do you have a EclipseLink version that already supports this? And can't you use @EJB, like in the example of your provided link?

Comment: Looks like issue with glassfish 4.1 and Eclipselink 2.5.2 version - https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/209. Are you guys able to upgrade EclipseLink 2.6 with glassfish 4.1 server successfully?

Comment: prepersist and preupdate are important part of application. can you please let me know, any other workaround you guys have implemented ? with Eclipselink 2.5.2 and glassfish 4.1